# How can I convert char to byte?

Tags: char, type-conversion, byte

I have simple question.
As we know that `Char` takes two bytes (16 bit), and `Byte` takes one byte(8 bits).
But in many programming languages there is a function that converts `Char` to `Byte`. How it is possible to convert `Char` to `Byte` without losing anything?

Comment: I mean how to place 16 bit information to half of it, to 8 bit

Comment: I got downvote for this question. BUT in `SCALA` lang. it has method that converts `CHAR` to `BYTE` and this is named `toByte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# and java char is a 16 bit Unicode character. In other (older?) languages (C, C++, etc.) `char`s are 8 bit representations of ASCII characters. In those languages it makes sense to convert the types without losing anything.

In C# you can convert `char`s to twice as many `byte`s, or assume (be sure really) that the `char`s that you are trying to convert are 8 bit `char`s (look at the ASCII table) written as Unicode `char`s.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. I don't think there are any language shipped with such a function. For example, Java has `String.getBytes`, C# has `Encoding.GetBytes`, what they get are `byte`s, not `byte`. This kind of conversion  is just like cast from `short[]` to `char[]` in C, very simple, no manipulation, just casting, the size of the whole object (the total number the bytes) remains the same; nothing is lost.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but in SCALA  Char is 16bit, and it has toByte function that returns 8bit value of that char, maybe it is not caring about value overflow

Comment: I just checked the scala API, its Char class does have a toByte. But I think what it does is just an unsafe cast, like `int i = 42;char c = (char)i;`, if a UTF-16 character represents an ASCII char, it's okay to cast it from the wide char to a byte, because unicode is a superset of ASCII, the character's value between 0 and 127 has the same meaning of ASCII's counterpart. But whenever the text includes chars beyond ASCII, e.g. German or Chinese, casting this way will produce junks.

Comment: Yes Need4Steed you're right, it is unsafe casting. I also checked that